# Corda drain flows on a node that won't start

Tags: corda

One of my nodes won't start due to flows in limbo.

```
[ERROR] 2019-03-29T14:42:16,501Z [main] internal.Node.run - Found checkpoint for flow: class com.disney.frozen.LetItGo$CantHoldItBackAnymore that is no longer installed. Please install the missing CorDapp, drain your node (see https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#flow-drains), and try again. {}
```

I understand how to drain flows when the node is up with `setFlowsDrainingModeEnabled`
**But how do you drain them when the node won't start?**
This particular occurence was in Corda 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `setFlowsDrainingModeEnabled enabled: true` + restart + set back to false has been performed, you may still have persitent checkpoints.
In my case I had to **delete NODE_CHECKPOINTS** from the node DB and restart the node.
There is a feature in the node that breaks flows compatibility if you change the CorDapp jar. 
A mere compilation for example would make flows incompatible between "versions".

Answer (score 0):

I´d like add some infos about solution case:
If **there is'nt acess to Corda CLI** for operation, or swapped different versions of cordapps maybe should consider add :

```
devMode=true
devMode Options.allowCompatibilityZone=true
```

in your node.conf.

After this should use the best solution above. tks